# LaTeX template for thesis not compiling

Tags: compiling

I have been given a LaTeX template by my university. They just sent me this folder (see picture).

They told me that `diss.tex` is the main file. I also put the error picture when compiling `diss.tex`.

I'm using TeXmaker on Ubuntu and I was used to have only one `.tex`-file, here I have many. Please help!

Dropbox Link Folder: www.dropbox.com/sh/n7bosdkh6bdj29p/AABX6zAaxj0DolOjjmoyANEFa?dl=0

[image]
[image: The folder of the latex model]

Comment: what is your question? what did you do, what error did you get. How can anyone help if you ask no question and just show an image of a file list????

Comment: Judging by the presence of Makefile, there is a compilation procedure that your university advises. Please post the content of any example `.tex` file and of the Makefile.

Comment: As novice to LaTeX I recommend you first to read some basic literature about LaTeX, for example *The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε* (https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf}), then provide minimal working example (the code, not images), a complete short document, which will show your problem. You should also give to us some description what you doing ...

Comment: I followed a tutorial on latex. I know how to work with just one .tex. With separeted .tex files, I'm new.

Comment: It confuses me that a university provides a tool but does not provide the information needed to use that tool.

Comment: They suppose you have installed latexlive-full, but the default installation of texmaker is not full and I hadn't percepted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says the compiler cannot find `abntex2cite.sty` file. Just download it from [here](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/tex/abntex2cite.sty) and put it alongside `diss.tex' file.

Comment: I solved it by "sudo apt-get install texlive-full"

Comment: The command basically installs a full package of latex compiler which also includes abnex2cite.sty.

Answer (score 0):

Several files with .tex are always to make it easier to manage big projects,
usually the main file contain `\include{file name}`or `\input{file name}` to include the other chapters.
And for the the errors there is a missing package you have to download it from here[Ctan](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/tex#abntex2cite.sty).
If you can use miktex (only on Windows ) it gives you an option while you set it up to download the required package without asking.

Note : at least read the not so short introduction to `\LaTeX` it won't take a lot of time.